# Can linear Kalman filter estimates states for nonlinear systems?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, kalman-filter

Assume that we have your dynamical system:

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k)+Bu(k)$$

When we simulate it inside a computer, it looks like straight equation:

$$y(k) = kx(k) + m = Cx(k) + Du(k)$$

But our real dynamical system is the sin wave equation when we run the simulation in real life.

$$y(k) = \sin(x(k)) = f(x(k),u(k))$$

Kalman filter

$$\hat x(k+1) = A \hat x(k) - KC \hat x(k) + Bu(k) + Ky(k)$$

**Question:**

If we using a linear Kalman filter $K$ and basic state feedback. Can our Kalman filter then estimate the states of the sine wave?

$$\sin(x(k)) \approx \sin(\hat x(k))$$

I want to estimate states for a rotary arm, and see if a linear Kalman filter can do the job if I have state feedback.

Comment: It is reasonable to consider the Extended Kalman filter (EKF), which is based on dynamics linearization along your trajectory.

Comment: @Arastas but are you sure ? What if a spring mass system without damping ?

Comment: What is your expected operating range? For example if $-\pi/2<x(k)<\pi/2$ you could just use $\sin^{-1}(y(k))$ for the correction term.

Comment: Do you mean that your $x(k)$ is a scalar? Otherwise the output $\sin(x)$ is not properly defined. Note also that your problem statement is deterministic, and it is not convenient for Kalman filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you mean $y_k=\sin(Cx_k)$, where $Cx$ is a scalar. Otherwise, either your $x$ is a scalar (and $C=1$), or you should specify the $\sin(x)$ function.

Ok, so let us define the estimation error signal as $\tilde{x}:=\hat{x}-x$. Suppose that $|\tilde{x}|$ is small. Then the following approximation holds $$\sin(Cx)\approx \sin(C\hat{x}) - \cos(C\hat{x})C\tilde{x},$$
or equivalently $\sin(C\hat{x})\approx \sin(Cx) + \cos(Cx)C\tilde{x}$.

Now for the observer $$\hat{x}_{k+1} = A\hat{x}_k + Bu_k + K\left(y-\sin(C\hat{x}_k)\right)$$ the error dynamics approximation is given by $$\tilde{x}_{k+1} = \left(A - \cos(C\hat{x}_k)KC\right)\tilde{x}_k.$$
Or you can alternatively approximate it as $$\tilde{x}_{k+1} = \left(A - \cos(Cx_k)KC\right)\tilde{x}_k.$$
If you have some ideas about your trajectory, e.g., $x$ remains close to the origin and $\cos({Cx})\approx 1$, then you have a linear system. If $Cx$ remains in a small sector close to zero then you can find a constant $K$ ensuring stability, e.g., via linear matrix inequalities (LMIs). If $Cx$ significantly rotates and $\cos(Cx)$ changes its sign then you need a parameter-varying observer, where $K=K(y,\hat{x})$.

Note that this analysis is based on the idea that $\tilde{x}_0$ is small enough and $\tilde{x}_k$ remains small enough.

Comment: So the conclusion is that linear kalman filter is not for robotics ? Like a robotic arm?

Comment: First, it is not a Kalman filter, it is a Luenberger-like observer. Second, it depends on your problem. Robotics, in general, is too wide to say something precise.

Comment: well, i just thinking on rotary systems. Is luenberger observer better for nonlinear systems ?

Comment: Luenberger is a linear observer for linear systems. There does not exist a general observer for general nonlinear systems, it is a design problem. You have to specify your system, what are the measurements, what are the reasonable assumption, and so on. I have shown you one possible (approximation-based Luenberger-like) solution under the assaumption that your initial guess is good enough.

Comment: Ok! Thank you. The reason why I asking is because I only create models from data e.g systemidentification. I'm using the subspace identification methods. Try to simulate this model. I have estimate it from $y=sin(t)$ where $t$ is time vector. $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
 0.98017  & 0.19905 \\
      -0.19905  & 0.97976 
\end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix}
0.022206 \\
       0.446716
\end{bmatrix}, C = \begin{bmatrix}
-0.022206 &  0.446716 
\end{bmatrix}, D = \begin{bmatrix}
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: It works perfect. In this case, it must be possible to say that a linear model, can behave as nonlinear for some cases such as trigonometric functions? Simulate the model with $u(t) = 1 \forall t$ Trigonometric functions is the only that matters for robotic arms.

Comment: Can even estimate 10th order models for y = cos(t).*(sin(t) + cos(sin(t)));